# Custom tab menu using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a custom tabbed menu with some css modification, I wanto to make something like this:

[image: small tab]

I was able to create something very close using display flex:

HTML:

```
<div class="mod-mini-menu">
   <ul>
      <li class="active">
         <a href="#">Active</a>       
      </li>
      <li>
         <hr class="verticalLine" />
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#">Inactive</a>      
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mod-mini-menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #272727;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

.mod-mini-menu li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%
}

.mod-mini-menu li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.mod-mini-menu .active a {
    color: #4CAF50;
}

.verticalLine {
    border: none;
    border-left: 1px solid hsla(200, 10%, 50%, 100);
    height: 70%;
    width: 1px;
}
```

There are problems with this approach, first, I want to make a separation between each li elements, I din't know how to make this in a simpler way, so the thing I came up to was to set a hr in between each 2 li elements, I know this is not the best solution for that but I didn't know a better way, how could I make it properly?

Other thing is that I'm not able to center the text in each separation, I was trying to set text align on li elements but nothing.

My goal at the end of the day is make this custom tab adjust to the elements inside, for example:

[image: big tab]

Adapting itself to the with of the parent div.

This is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqJbVd) of the above code.

Can anyone guide me on this?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**
You don't need `hr` tag.. You can set the `border-left` on `li` tag except first li.

Below CSS can help you to achieve that.

```
.mod-mini-menu li:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: 1px solid hsla(200, 10%, 50%, 100);
}
```

check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pxamox)

**Option 2:**
If you want the solution with hr only then you can add `:nth-child(odd)` after `li` css where you are setting width (100%).

```
.mod-mini-menu li:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
    width: 100%
}
```

You can check it [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OBQYjZ)